# Checking Okta Session Status After Local Logout in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, okta

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot application that utilizes Okta for authentication. My objective is to implement a local logout mechanism in the application without invalidating the Okta session. Subsequently, when users revisit the application, I want to determine the Okta session status (active or inactive) without automatically logging them in. Here are the key points:

1. I've a local logout in my Spring Boot application.
2. After local logout, I need to check whether the Okta session is still active when users attempt to log in again.
3. The goal is to return a boolean value (true if the Okta session is active, false if not) without automatically logging in the user.

Any insights, code snippets, or guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just initiate a new authorization-code flow.

If the user still have an opened session on the authorization server, the OAuth2 client will get tokens silently (without the authorization server prompting the user for his credentials).

Comment: like "login under the hood"?

Comment: No, just authorized client creation under the hood. "Login / Logout"  state reference is the authorization server. If you don't Logout a user from the authorization server (RP-Initiated Logout?) and if the user session on the authorization server, then the user is still logged-in and the authorization-code flow can complete silently.

Comment: but I don't want to redirect users to Okta login page on browser if the Okta session is invalid

Comment: I'm afraid that what you want won't have much impact on the standard. You want new tokens for a user? You need an authorization-code. You want an authorization-code? You have to ask your user to get one from the authorization server. You don't want to do that? Then don't close your session or don't use OAuth2.